# How to obtain datafeed from google spreadsheet and use the data

Tags: jquery, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Being rather noob, i can't seem to find a solution to this, even thou there are many posts on the subject.

I am trying to make this interactive timeline work, using data from a google spreadsheet.

What i am looking for, is how to get the Json feed into the system.

I have it working (don't mind the lack of styling) with a local Json file
 [example](http://torbenvf.dk/ledelsehelehistorien/4/)

That is from a local json file.

I want the feed to come from this 
[spreadsheet feed](https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1X3U-Cvof4ofu8EDyIv4MqDqrlF-D9ZrRK0rJsA_zUwM/od6/public/values?)

So, i thought this ought to work, replacing the  `$.getJSON('database.json', function(data`)

with  `$.getJSON('https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1X3U-Cvof4ofu8EDyIv4MqDqrlF-D9ZrRK0rJsA_zUwM/od6/public/values?alt=json', function(data)`

But it isn't.

I made the Json file, from the spreadsheet.

Are there any sugestions?

kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this instead.

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1X3U-Cvof4ofu8EDyIv4MqDqrlF-D9ZrRK0rJsA_zUwM/od6/public/values?alt=json',
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(data) {
                    var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                    $('#results').html('Version: ' + json.version + '<br />Encoding: ' + json.encoding);
                }
            });
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hmm.. It just tells me to enable cors.

Comment: Just put www.corsproxy.com before the url like this. 

 $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.corsproxy.com/spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1X3U-Cvof4ofu8EDyIv4MqDqrlF-D9ZrRK0rJsA_zUwM/od6/public/values?alt=json',
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(data) {
                    var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                    console.log(json)
                    alert(json)
                    $('#results').html('Version: ' + json.version + '<br />Encoding: ' + json.encoding);
                }
            });